# How to create a loop for sublists of array

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a loop where for each element in a sublist, I substitute it in a formula. For example,

```
output = [[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 6], [1, 8]]
y = 1**2 + 2
y2 = 1**2 + 4
y3 = 1**2 + 6
y4 = 1**2 + 8
```

and so on. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: so formula is ```x**2 + y```?

Comment: yes, the formula is x**2 + y

Comment: `for x, y in output:`....?

Comment: ```answers=[x**2+y for x,y in output]```?

Comment: "Is there an easy way to do that?" -- yes, and it seems that the point of the homework assignment is for you to figure out what that easy way is. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **destructure** the sublist `[x, y]` into `x` and `y` and then use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to write the result into a list using only one line of code. *(credits to Sujay's comment)*

```
results=[x**2+y for x, y in output]
```

This is equal to:

```
result = []
for x, y in output:
    result.append(x**2 + y)
```

Comment: The first one looks like my comment (```;-)```)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
def function(n):
    a = []
    for i in range(2, n*2 +2, 2):
        a.append([1, i])
    return a
print(function(5))
```

Output for n=4:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 6], [1, 8]]
```

Or the inverse input:

```
output = [[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 6], [1, 8]]
def function(n):
    a = ""
    for i in range(len(n)):
        a += "y = 1**2 " + " + " + str(n[i][1]) + "\n"
    return a
print(function(output))
```

Output of the second code:

```
y = 1**2  + 2
y = 1**2  + 4
y = 1**2  + 6
y = 1**2  + 8
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added the inverse code

Answer (score 0):

I assume all of your sublists will contain 2 elements.

You can define a custom function operate_on_sublist, which you can later apply to each sublist by using map. Check the code below

```
def operate_on_sublist(output):
    return (output[0]**2) + output[1]

output = [[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 6], [1, 8]]

squared = list(map(operate_on_sublist, output))

#Prints [3, 5, 7, 9]
print(squared)
```